# Recognizing end of file while reading 16 bit ints from a binary file

Tags: c++

I have some problems recognizing EOF in this code. The file `table.bin` contains byte pairs representing 16 bit ints. They are divided into groups separated by two 0x0 bytes.

The code correctly reads all the data in the file, and then somehow inserts a `{ 0xF00D, {} }` key/value pair into the table which indicates that it reads more data than it should. How do I correctly check for EOF here?

`UChar` is a typedef of `std::uint16_t`

```
std::map<UChar, std::vector<UChar>> table;
std::vector<UChar> v;
std::ifstream ifs("table.bin", std::ios::binary);
UChar n;
while (ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof n))
{
    if (n != 0x0)
        v.push_back(n);
    else
    {
        table.insert(std::make_pair(v.front(), v));
        v.clear();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is the number of entries in the table greater than the number of bytes in the file / 2?  I tested with a 9 byte file and successfully read 4 shorts and the loop ended as expected when the next short could not be read.

Comment: @RetiredNinja no. The file contains an even number of bytes, and the last byte pair is `00 00`, so 0x0 if read as `std::uint16_t`. The code then reads data that isn't in the file, and only then terminates.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to trace through it in the debugger to see what's going on.  The loop should end as soon as a read fails.  Is `UChar` a >= 16-bit type?

Comment: @RetiredNinja no, it's actually a typedef of std::uint16_t but used to be a 32 bit type initially. Apologies if it was a confusing. I have clarified the code now (which still produces the same results, so that wasn't the issue).

Comment: That code looks fine, I'd suspect an issue with the data.

Comment: it must be the `v.front()` on a "cleared" v, I don't see any other issue, unless there's something odd you do later that you didn't show us.

Answer (score 0):

Further inspecting your code, the issue seems not to be how you check for EOF. Even if there are spurious data at the end of your stream, you won't read those unless they are multiple of `sizeof n`.

What happens if you find two `0` values? Your second `v.front()` causes undefined behaviour (you cleared v on the previous 0), and that is the only idea I have about the fact that you find extraneous data in your `map`. So, inspect your data, and update us about it.

Comment: `read` returns the stream and if it is bad then the loop should end.  Checking `eof` explicitly isn't necessary, it's enough to know the read failed.

Comment: correct. I think I haven't understood the OP issue well then. Will check it again later, thanks.